# Phone mask depending on URL

Tags: javascript, mask

Using a script to enter a phone number by mask. Here is the part of the code that does this:

```
let t = $("input[type=tel]");
$.each(t, function() {
    $(this).mask("+38 (000) 000-00-00")
});
```

How to change the mask depending on the url or html lang=""?

- /en/ - 000-000-000-000
- /uk/ - +38 (000) 000-00-00
- /ru/ - +38 (000) 000-00-00

Comment: Use a `switch` statement, or store the masks in an object using the language identifier as key, so that you can access them directly ...

Comment: Why would `/uk/` be different to `/en/`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let t = $("input[type=tel]");
    $.each(t, function() {
        $("html").is('[lang="en-GB"]') ? $(this).mask("000-000-000-000") : $(this).mask("+38 (000) 000-00-00")
    });
```